# How to get UIImage from NSDictionary in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimage, nsdictionary

I have searched more and more but didn't get the perfect solution.
I have saved an image in a dictionary.

```
@{
   ......
   @"PrdImg":[UIImage imageNamed:[image objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
   ......
 };
```

The image data saved perfectly. I checked it. 
But when I want to get this data from the dictionary then an exception encountered. The retrieving code is giving below.

```
PoctImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:PrdDetailsDic[@"PrdImg"]];
```

The encountered exception is -

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9428e4e930'

I have also read more document about the exception. But didn't get the specific solution.

Now I want to know how can I get the image data from the dictionary. What is the specific syntax for getting the image from the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

The initializer `UIImage imageNamed:` is looking for the image in your main bundle, and since you've got it in a dictionary it won't find it.  If you're actually storing a `UIImage` in the dictionary, why not just say...

```
PoctImage.image = PrdDetailsDic[@"PrdImg"];
```

I also suspect there's an issue with trying to save an image to the dictionary in the way you specify, for the same reason.  It seems like that one should be...

```
@{
......
@"PrdImg":[image objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
......
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , problem is fixed.